# Corda SQLGrammarException after changing the Schema file name

Tags: hibernate, jpa, corda

I used to have my `PersistentState`s in separate files, which was causing a lot of warnings at node startup telling:

```
! ATTENTION: Cross-reference between MappedSchemas 'DealSchemaV1' and 
'CompanySchemaV1'. MappedSchema 'SharedDealSchemaV1' entity 
'PersistentSharedDealParticipant' field 'invitedBy' is of type 
'PersistentPartyAndCompany' defined in another MappedSchema 
'CompanySchemaV1'. This may cause issues when evolving MappedSchema or 
migrating its data, ensure JPA entities are defined within the same 
enclosing MappedSchema.
```

So I decided to move them all into one enclosing file. Nothing else was changed, all tables names, column names etc. everything is just the same, the only thing that was changed is the location of `PersistentStates`s.

No when I run the node I see no warnings, but when I try to create a state which is recording something in Persistent DB I get this error:

```
aused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "SCHEMAV1$PERSISTENTCOMPANY_OUTPUT_INDEX" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Company_CompanyRole (SchemaV1$PersistentCompany_output_index, SchemaV1$PersistentCompany_transaction_id, roles_database_id) values (?, ?, ?) [42122-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:682) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumn(Parser.java:936) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnList(Parser.java:920) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsertGivenTable(Parser.java:1258) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1222) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:431) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:307) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:304) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:310) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1314) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    ... 30 more
```

When I do a clean run with clean DB I don't get this error.

How can I fix this error? Should I do DB migration? I thought that if I don't change anything in the table/column names/types I will not have to do migration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to changed the schema after you had created some states using the old schema. This might be the cause of the issue. The CorDapp now is trying to looking at the database with the new schema and found the a different schema. Thus, it creates an error.

Speaking of implementing schema, you can either do it

all-in-one like this: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Features/queryableState-carinsurance/contracts/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/schema/InsuranceSchemaV1.kt

separated files like https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Features/queryablestate-carinsurance/contracts/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/carinsurance/schema.

They are virtually the same.